# Selecting with filters

Tags: sql, database, ado

I'm developing a booking system for a clinic, so my aim is that i want to display available doctor shift which are not already reserved, the patient check the availability of a certain doctor in specific date and shift.
I have 2 tables

```
Booking (ID, DocID, shift_id, Date)
Shift (ID, name, DocID)
```

MySQL selecting query which is not working is:

```
SELECT  Shift.ID, Shift.name, Shift.DocID
FROM    Shift INNER JOIN
        Booking ON Shift.ID = Booking.shift_id
WHERE   (Shift.DocID = @DoctorID) AND (Booking.DocID <> @DoctorID) 
 AND    (Booking.shift_id <> @ShiftID) AND (Booking.Date <> @VisitDate)
```

so please any ideas???

Comment: Does it return an error message? If so, please edit your post to include it.

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```
SELECT s.* FROM Shift
LEFT JOIN Booking b 
    ON s.id = b.shift_id
   AND s.DocID = b.DocID
WHERE b.id IS NULL
   OR b.date <> visit_date
```

Answer (score 0):

Left join method:

```
SELECT s.* FROM Shift s
LEFT JOIN Booking b 
    ON s.id = b.shift_id
   AND s.DocID = b.DocID
   AND b.date = @visit_date
WHERE s.ID = @ShiftID and s.DocID = @DocID and b.id IS NULL
```

You could also write variants using NOT EXISTS or NOT IN clauses - the point is that you want shifts where there is no booking for that doctor, for that shift, on that day

Comment: @user1071629, Which answer is working? Marco and I have posted significantly different queries, which should produce significantly different results.